# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException while jClouds MS Azure Blob put operation

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, jclouds

I am facing issue with jClouds AzureBlob API with put operation

```
context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().createContext(
                    this.storageType,
                    this.storageAccount, 
                    this.primaryAccessKey);

    BlobStore blobStore = context.getBlobStore();
                Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(fileName).payload(content).build(); //$NON-NLS-1$
                blobStore.putBlob(this.containerName, blob);
```

I am setting primary access key from manage access key -> Primary access key for my storage account.

It gives me following error

```
org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty connecting to PUT https://mypackages.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ERROR/error_20130717022518962.xml HTTP/1.1
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.call(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:173)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.call(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:130)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.config.ExecutorServiceModule$DescribingExecutorService.submit(ExecutorServiceModule.java:184)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.submit(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:127)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.submit(TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.java:54)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandImpl.execute(TransformingHttpCommandImpl.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.createListenableFutureForHttpRequestMappedToMethodAndArgs(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:198)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.invoke(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy295.putBlob(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_43]
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.internal.SyncProxy.invoke(SyncProxy.java:137)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy296.putBlob(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.azureblob.blobstore.AzureBlobStore.putBlob(AzureBlobStore.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_43]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:37)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy287.putBlob(Unknown Source)
```

In above stack trace "ERROR/error_20130717022518962.xml " is the file I am trying to put on the blob storage.

Any clue, how to resolve this?

Comment: I am aware, this could be 1. truststore has not been set or can not be accessed. But the thing is this was working since months and suddenly started giving error. There is no change in environment or code. Hence  please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, actually code which is invoking ReST PUT for azure blob storage.
was somehow not able to load java default trust-store.

By adding below line to load default cacert

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",PATH_TO_CACERT);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",PASSWORD);
```